# Node.js Handlebars {{object}} does not render inside {{each}} loop, but renders outside of loop (and other {{object_names}} render within the loop)

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js

I am using Express, Node, & Handlebars and I can't figure out why my {{object_one}} won't render within an {{each}} loop, but it renders {{object_two}} from within and {{object_one}} outside.

Here is example since I'm not sure I'm describing this well:

```
{{#each inline_upsell_amounts}}
<div class="col-4"><a href="{{base_url}}?{{#if inline_ab_refcode}}refcode={{inline_ab_refcode}}&{{/if}}">$ {{this}}</a></div>
{{/each}}

<p>This shows the 'base_url' value: {{base_url}}</p>
```

So inside the loop base_url renders as empty or ''. the value of base_url is a string (url 'http://something.com' ).

It renders correct outside of the each loop, and {{inline_ab_refcode}} also a string renders fine within the loop.

I've tried different names, different values, making a helper, wrapping with IF. I can't figure out this odd bug I have.

Hopefully it's something silly that you can see?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You miss something : in the loop {{base_url}} is not the same as outside the loop :
In the loop {{base_url}} is actually {{inline_upsell_amounts.0.base_url}} or {{inline_upsell_amounts.1.base_url}} and so on ... outside of it it is {{base_url}}. Because the argument of the loop becomes the new reference.

What you can do is refer to the parent item and use {{../base_url}} inside the loop and {{base_url}} outside. If you need a reference that is always the same you can also use {{@root/base_url}} that will always be the base_url of the root element.

So your code will look like that :

```
{{#each inline_upsell_amounts}}
<div class="col-4"><a href="{{../base_url}}?{{#if inline_ab_refcode}}refcode={{inline_ab_refcode}}&{{/if}}">$ {{this}}</a></div>
{{/each}}

<p>This shows the 'base_url' value: {{base_url}}</p>
```

I hope I've been clear enough.

Comment: Thank you this worked! I didn't see the ../ folder type object access in the handlebars each loop examples